# Zipping outlook attachment on the fly

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, email-attachments, vspackage

I'm developing a Visual Studio extension that adds a command to VS to compose a message in Outlook with an attachment. The attachment is simple .csv file that is also produced by the extension. 
So when user fires the command, outlook opens a window with an email already composed and attachment added. The user might just click send.

Now I've been asked to add possibility to send those logs compressed with zip. I would like to compose a message with an attachment already compressed, but I don't want any temporary .zip files retained after message is sent (or cancelled). How can I achieve this?

My code that composes the message and opens Outlook window:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

...

    private static bool TrySendMethod1(string subject, string toAddr, string body, string logPath)
    {
        try
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Subject = subject;
            mailItem.To = toAddr;
            mailItem.Body = body;
            if (logPath != null) mailItem.Attachments.Add(logPath);
            mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
            mailItem.Display(false);
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**update**
Once the email is composed, an outlook window with a composed message is displayed (it has the attachment already set). Now, the user might just send it, cancel it or whatever. He might even leave the window opened for hours (although this is not common) and then send it (even after VS has been closed). Again, i don't want any temporary archives to exist on the disk after the message is sent or cancelled.

I added full method that sends the email. It's not much more, but this method is just invoked when user selects a new Visual Studio command that my extension adds to it (tools -> send TFS logs -> from this month). There just an additional method between button handler and it simply sets some parameters for the one presented here (sets the subject, logPath and so on...)

**If it's not possible, then I can also accept such an answer.**

Comment: Please add the more code. Where do you actually send the mail? Because this is the place where you can remove the zipped file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compress a file using this:

```
public static void Compress(FileInfo fileToCompress, string compressedFileName)
{
    using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead())
    {
       using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(compressedFileName)
            {
                using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Modified from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx

For deleting the file afterwards you can attach to the `MailItem.Unload Event`.

> This event occurs after the Close event for the Outlook item occurs,
>   but before the Outlook item is unloaded from memory, allowing an
>   add-in to release any resources related to the object. Although the
>   event occurs before the Outlook item is unloaded from memory, this
>   event cannot be canceled.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868564(v=office.15).aspx

Then you TrySendMethod1 could look like this

```
private static bool TrySendMethod1(string subject, string toAddr, string body, string logPath)
{
    try
        {
          Application app = new Application();
          MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
          mailItem.Subject = subject;
          mailItem.To = toAddr;
          mailItem.Body = body;
          string compressedFileName = logpath + ".gz";
          CompressedStack(logpath, compressedFileName);
          if (logPath != null) mailItem.Attachments.Add( compressedFileName );
          mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
          mailItem.Display(false);
          mailItem.Unload += (e) => {File.Delete(compressedFileName);};
          return true;
      }
      catch (System.Exception e)
      {
          return false;
      }
  }
```

Exception handling for the `File.Delete` is missing, and I am not sure 100% certaing about the signature of the `Unload` event, but have a try and let us know.

This will NOT handle the case where Visual Studio is closed BEFORE the mail is sent! (I think that might not even be possible.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be ".gz" when you're attaching it to the email, instead of ".zip"?

Comment: Will the new "log.gz" exist somewhere on disk after executing Compress(log). If so, then it's not what I want. I want to be sure, that after user sends the composed mail, no unnecessary files are on the disk.

Comment: The file must be there until you send the mail. You need to delete the file manually after the mail has been sent. Doing fileToCompress.FullName + ".gz" to create a filename is the very simple way, you could also specify a different filename (as parameter for example) and remove it later.

Comment: I would explain to him that the file gets created at the same location as the original due to the path option chosen and maybe demonstrate how he can choose a different location.  This code works, though.

Comment: @B.K.: He needs to provide a bit more information how he is sending the mails.